# How to connect internet within a qemu(linux based) running on a linux based host machine with company proxy server

Tags: proxy, qemu, qemu-device

I can run ping google and check internet connection status when running on a host without proxy
[without company proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q6tT.png)

But when host has proxy running on it then from within qemu i am not able to connect internet
[with company proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OV0m.png)

tried to set company proxy inside qemu but still no use